# ctypes.memmove appears to hang

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a few questions regarding Python's ctypes.memmove.  It appears the execution hangs when executing this line of code:

```
ctypes.memmove(ctypes.addressof(self.regData), bin_bytes[offset:offset + size], size)
```

- The Python class defines `self.regData` as `("regData", ctypes.c_uint32 * 107520),`.  so its size is 430,080 and assigned to the variable `size`
- The variable `bin_bytes` is an argument passed into the class which is data read from a binary file into a variable, `binary_data`.  `bin_bytes` is defined by `self.binary_data[section_offset:next_section_offset]`).  Its size is 220,341.

  I believe the problem is because `size` is larger than the size of `bin_bytes`.  Also, I don't understand what `bin_bytes[offset:offset + size]` is doing.  Is this passing in the address starting at `offset`?  What is `:offset + size` doing in this case?   What is the behavior of Python and ctypes when calling memmove wtih an offset outside the range of one of the parameters?  Will this behave just like C thus just access the memory at the offset starting at the array address?

  I did try wrapping the ctypes.memmove around a `try/except Exception as err` block, but the code still appears to hang within the memmove call.  Thanks.

Edit: Python version is v2.7.10

Comment: `bin_bytes[offset:offset+size]` creates a new bytes buffer, starting at item `offset` going through `offset+size`.  If `size` is larger than `bin_bytes`, then that should have thrown a Python exception before ever calling `memmove`.  `memmove` itself has no knowledge of Python; it's C code, so it will blindly copy that many bytes, whether they're part of an object or not.

Comment: Make a [mcve].  Include all code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I will attempt to make a small example.

Comment: Can you show us the code?  I'm suspicious of how you have created `self.regData`.  If it is not actually a buffer, then you would be randomly writing over code and data, which could of course cause a hang.